# get SonarQube PR decoration status from Bitbucket rest api

Tags: rest, sonarqube, bitbucket

I am trying to get the SonarQube PR decoration status via Bitbucket Rest API.
[image: bitbucket sonarqube PR decoration]

I think that the report key that was stored in bitbucket via SonarQube integration is com.sonarsource.sonarqube

Is it possible and if yes how?
Thank you